# Camera.Maui Snapshot result does not fit preview

Tags: maui

I'm using this Nuget Plugin: https://github.com/hjam40/Camera.MAUI
I try to take a snapshot of the camerafeed. Its working, but the angle in the result is different one:

[image]

As you can see, the result-image shows more from the top and less from the bottom. I'm playing around with aspect property of the image but the problem might be that the camerafeed just showing a cutout.

myView:

```
<VerticalStackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <cv:CameraView x:Name="cameraView" WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="300" CamerasLoaded="CameraView_CamerasLoaded" AutoSnapShotFormat="PNG"/>
        <Button Text="Smile" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
        <Image x:Name="myIMage" WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="300" Clip="ToBounds"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
```

Code behind:

```
private async void CameraView_CamerasLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cameraView.Camera = cameraView.Cameras.First();

    if (cameraView.NumCamerasDetected > 0)
    {
 
        MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            await cameraView.StopCameraAsync();
            await cameraView.StartCameraAsync();
        });
        
    }
}

private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    myIMage.Source = cameraView.GetSnapShot();
}
```

I allready created a issue in the repo (https://github.com/hjam40/Camera.MAUI/issues/98) but it seems the creator is'nt active anymore, the last comment is months ago.
Anyone had the same problem or has any recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the capture didn't match the preview. While reviewing the plugin code, I found something that, in my case, fixed the error

[Camera.Maui plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TR9tg.png)

In this line, a 0 was being passed for the x and y positions, which represent the starting point of the bitmap. However, if the preview does not match the maximum screen camera size, that offset must be considered.

```
 bitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(bitmap, (bitmap.Width - Width)/2, (bitmap.Height - Height) / 2, Width, Height);
```